# I am developing firefox extension and wanted to count total number of text box of webpage so how to count text box?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing firefox extension and wanted to count total number of text box of webpage so how to count text box using javascript?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to count the textboxes *on* a page?  Also can you show what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Yes I want to count the total number of input text boxes on a webpage..I am able to count those text boxes whose type ="text" but how to identify those text boxes whose type is password or Email..Lets take an example of FACEBOOK registration page..my program has counted total number of text box is 6 while this page has 7 text boxes as 1 text box is there as type='password'

Answer (score 3):

Select them and count with `length`

```
var textboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').length
```

Comment: I have used "var textboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').length" but this is not able to count those text boxes whose type is password or email then how to count those text boxes..should i need to write a regex

Comment: To select inputs with other types you have to add them to the selector `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]')` -> http://jsfiddle.net/rK8C3/

Comment: Is there any other way as I am developing that extension with unlimited types option and it is not possible to add all the types available on other websites. Is there any way or any other method where i don't need to put all the types which i know,because type of input boxes may vary site by site..

Comment: You can target all inputs `document.querySelectorAll('input')` but that selects `<input type="button" />` as well. There is no general selector for everything that looks like a textbox, but there aren't that many types to add either ?

Comment: Thanks @adeneo for your valuable answers..

Comment: How to ignore hidden elements?

Comment: Then it gets more complicated, and you'd probably have to filter() the collection if you're not going to use a library, like jQuery. That's something that should be asked in a new question I think.